# AngularJS Chained Promises only work once

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function that retrieves a lot of data based on user selection of checkboxes.  If the user selects "All", the function uses chained promises to fetch the selected data based on the "id" of each checkbox.  It works perfectly the first time the user selects "All".  However, if the user deselects "All" then selects "All" once again, the chained promises no longer chain.  It goes to the first promise and then stalls.  If the page is refreshed the chained promises will work again.  The code below is just a snippet to present the "general idea" because there is a lot of code involved.  Somehow it seems as if the original promises are not cleared or something, but I can't figure out the issue as I do not receive any errors.

This function is called when the user clicks the "Select All" button.

```
      $scope.selectAll = function () {
    $scope.print.sections = angular.copy($scope.sections);
  };
```

Then when the user clicks "Print Selected", the following function is called:

```
  $scope.printSections = function () {
  var promise = null;
  $scope.print.sections.sort(setOrder);
  $scope.dataLoading = true;

          var cntr = 0;
          var sections = $scope.print.sections;
          function next() {
              if (cntr < sections.length) {
                  promise = getSectionData(sections[cntr++]);
                  promise.then(next);
              }
          }
          next();



  };
```

The function "getSectionData" gets the data for each section by its "id".  This is not all of the code for this function as it is very long.

```
function getSectionData(section) {
    var deferred;
    deferred = $q.defer();
    var id = section.QuestionSectionID;
    switch (id) {
      case 1:

          deferred.resolve(myService.getfirstSection(id)
            .success(function (data) {
              $scope.firstSection = data;
            }));

        break;
     case 2:
          deferred.resolve(myService.getSecondSection(id)
            .success(function (data) {
              $scope.secondSection= data;
            }));

        break;
    }
return deferred.promise;
}
```

The problem is the second time around, the "next()" function which chains the promises does not work.
Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The following is pretty much a replica of your code, but without `$q` wrapper for `Promise`. The only thing that I think could be missing is the `default` option in `switch` to send a blank promise when case doesn't match.

```js
var cntr = 0;
var sections = [1, 2, 989878, 3]; //data for 989878 does not exist

function next() {
  if (cntr < sections.length) {
    promise = getSectionData(sections[cntr++]);
    promise.then(next);
  }
}
next();

function getSectionData(id) {

  var deferred = null;
  switch (id) {
    case 1:
      deferred = Promise.resolve(getOtherData(id).success(function(data) {
        $('pre').append(JSON.stringify(data[0], {}, ' '));
      }));
      break;
    case 2:
      deferred = Promise.resolve(getOtherData(id).success(function(data) {
        $('pre').append(JSON.stringify(data[0], {}, ' '));
      }));
      break;
    case 3:
      deferred = Promise.resolve(getOtherData(id).success(function(data) {
        $('pre').append(JSON.stringify(data[0], {}, ' '));
      }))
      break;
    default: //return a default promise object. Comment the default out and see what happens
      deferred = Promise.resolve(true);
      break;
  }
  return deferred;
}

function getOtherData(id) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users?id=' + id,
    method: 'GET'
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre>
  
</pre>
```